# What does `void 0` mean?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Reading through the Backbone.js source code, I saw this:

```
validObj[attr] = void 0;
```

What is `void 0`? What is the purpose of using it here?

Comment: The linked question about "void(0)" does not make it very clear that `void` is a special keyword with unique syntax.  I had no idea that `void(0)` and `void 0` were the same keyword until I found this question.

Answer (score 1187, accepted):

### What does `void 0` mean?

[`void`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) is a prefix keyword that takes one argument and always returns `undefined`.

**Examples**

```
void 0
void (0)
void "hello"
void (new Date())
//all will return undefined
```

### What's the point of that?

It seems pretty useless, doesn't it? If it always returns `undefined`, what's wrong with just using `undefined` itself?

In a perfect world we would be able to safely just use `undefined`: it's much simpler and easier to understand than `void 0`. But in case you've never noticed before, *this isn't a perfect world*, especially when it comes to Javascript.

The problem with using `undefined` was that `undefined` is not a reserved word ([it is actually a property of the global object <sup>[wtfjs]</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20160311231335/http://wtfjs.com/2010/02/15/undefined-is-mutable)). That is, `undefined` is a permissible variable name, so you could assign a new value to it at your own caprice.

```
alert(undefined); //alerts "undefined"
var undefined = "new value";
alert(undefined) // alerts "new value"
```

Note: This is no longer a problem in any environment that supports ECMAScript 5 or newer (i.e. in practice everywhere but IE 8), which defines the `undefined` property of the global object as read-only (so it is only possible to shadow the variable in your own local scope). However, this information is still useful for backwards-compatibility purposes.

```
alert(window.hasOwnProperty('undefined')); // alerts "true"
alert(window.undefined); // alerts "undefined"
alert(undefined === window.undefined); // alerts "true"
var undefined = "new value";
alert(undefined); // alerts "new value"
alert(undefined === window.undefined); // alerts "false"
```

`void`, on the other hand, cannot be overidden. `void 0` will *always* return `undefined`. `undefined`, on the other hand, can be whatever Mr. Javascript decides he wants it to be.

### Why `void 0`, specifically?

Why should we use `void 0`? What's so special about `0`? Couldn't we just as easily use `1`, or `42`, or `1000000` or `"Hello, world!"`?

And the answer is, yes, we could, and it would work just as well. The only benefit of passing in `0` instead of some other argument is that `0` is short and idiomatic.

### Why is this still relevant?

Although `undefined` can generally be trusted in modern JavaScript environments, there is one trivial advantage of `void 0`: it's shorter. The difference is not enough to worry about when writing code but it can add up enough over large code bases that most code minifiers replace `undefined` with `void 0` to reduce the number of bytes sent to the browser.

Comment: @PeterOlson the main benefit of `void 0` is that the `0` is the de-facto standard for using `void` to generate an `undefined` value.

Comment: First, `undefined` is not a keyword, it's just a property of the global object. Second, in ECMAScript5, it is write protected, so the `void 0` trick is only neccessary if someone uses `undefined` as a local variable within a function.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Unless you use strict mode, the trick *is* necessary because most browsers allow `undefined` to be mutated.

Comment: but why does it need a parameter? any useful examples of voiding an expression? why void 0? and not void 1?

Comment: @AntonN There might be some possible use cases where you want to execute a function that has side effects but ignore the return value.

Comment: So this is basically the same as `if (typeof options.something === 'undefined')` which I previously remembered from SO being the safe pattern for checking for undefinedness?

Comment: @Sam Not really, `void x` always *returns* undefined. `typeof x === "undefined"` checks if `x` is undefined.

Comment: Another common pattern is to provide `undefined` as an argument in an immediate function: `(function(undefined){ ... }())` Which is specially useful for minification.

Comment: Which JS engine will allow `undefined`'s value to be changed?

Comment: @RobertCambridge I think it's required by the ES5 spec, so it should be allowed by most JS engines.

Comment: Interesting that current versions of Chrome and Firefox don't then! :)

Comment: That same code alerts `undefined` when pasted into the console. I've seen odd things happen in the console, can't remember why or where I read about it though! Good to know.

Comment: @PeterOlson, in the example you're showing, you're creating a new local variable that hides the global one. The global `undefined` cannot be reassigned. The issue appears to be that `undefined` is not a reserved keyword. Try your fiddle again [without the `var` prefix](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/BRxZt/), making it an assignment rather than a declaration.

Comment: @RobertCambridge, see my prior comment for a clarification about why it doesn't work in Chrome's console. The original fiddle was hiding the global with a local. I agree with you that `undefined` cannot be reassigned in current Chrome or Firefox versions.

Comment: @DrewNoakes It's not a *local variable*, because I defined it in global scope. You are right, though, that the problem is not that `undefined` is changing, but that a variable is shadowing it.

Comment: @PeterOlson, it _is_ a local variable in the jsFiddle you linked to, as jsFiddle wraps the code in a function, ala: `window.onload = function() { var undefined = 4; alert(undefined); }`. Attempting to shadow the global on Chrome, Firefox and Node.JS doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: It seems like `void undefined` would be slightly clearer than `void 0`, no?

Comment: @finiteloop It would work just as well, but it's longer and possibly more confusing because `void 0` is a widely-known Javascript idiom whereas `void undefined` is less common and might cause people to think a little bit more about it.

Comment: @PeterOlson Yeah, you're probably right. As you can imagine I ended up on this thread because I hadn't seen void 0 before, but now that I have, I agree with your reasoning.

Comment: ok, so why `void 0` and not just `void`?

Comment: @WORMSS Because `void` requires an argument, so using it without anything after it would be a syntax error.

Comment: @PeterOlson yes, this I know, but I mean, WHY does void require an argument, since it doesn't matter what you pass to it?

Comment: @WORMSS That's a question for the language designers; I don't know

Comment: Makes sense what you said in your answer, but what I don't understand, is why the `void` keyword takes an argument? It returns `undefined` anyway, so why not just leave it as `return void` and nothing more?

Comment: Fun fact: because "undefined" can be a variable name, you can get ReferenceErrors in this case: `(() => {'use strict';alert(undefined);let undefined = 2;}())` (because "undefined" refers to the local variable in the next line, not the global property).

Comment: the old pattern `typeof myVar === 'undefined'` has the advantage of not throwing a ReferenceError in console where as `myVar === void 0` does, so can someone tell me why i should not keep using the old way for the "extra layer of safety" if they are otherwise functionally equivalent?

Answer (score 128):

`void 0` returns undefined and can not be overwritten while `undefined` can be overwritten.

```
var undefined = "HAHA";
```

Comment: ECMAScript 5 defines undefined as read-only

Comment: @licancabur: I believe that is in strict-mode code only, yes?

Comment: Wow, I keep getting downvotes on this. When this was posted 3 years ago, browsers allowed you to set undefined to any value.

Comment: If an answer becomes redundant over time why should it not be downvoted in favour of a more up-to-date answer?

Comment: @epascarello, Although what you wrote there is correct (somehow), but I don't think it is answering the question (clear enough) that is asking what does that mean.

Answer (score 42):

[`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/void) is a reserved JavaScript keyword. It evaluates the expression and always returns `undefined`.

Comment: It's probably shorter than `undefined`, and also is guaranteed to return it (unlike the global overwriteable `undefined`).