# How to understand "return obj === void 0" in the source of underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “javascript:void(0)” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)
>   [What does `void 0` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452341/what-does-void-0-mean)

In the file http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js, you can see such a code block:

```
// Is a given variable undefined?
_.isUndefined = function(obj) {
  return obj === void 0;
};
```

I don't understand the `void 0` part, it's very strange. How to understand it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452341/what-does-void-0-mean

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the console output

```
>typeof void 0
"undefined"
>void 0 === undefined
true
>"undefined".length
9
>"void 0".length
6
```

I think they are trying to save 3 bytes of file size ;)

*Edit:*
 This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7452352/973308) answer makes more sense of using `void 0`, as `undefined` is just a property of `window` object and is mutable. Hence `void 0` is a trusted way to generate undefined across browsers

Comment: Thanks, but is there explaination about "void 0"? I was thinking it's a function invocation of `void(0)` but missing the `()`. Seems incorrect.

Comment: `void` is almost like `typeof` which is not a function but an operator

Comment: That makes sense to understand.

Comment: This is infact wrong explanation. In Javascript you can override undefined: undefined = "foobar". void 0 is a way to say undefined in break-free manner.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Ya i understand and I just put up my thought http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452341/what-does-void-0-mean This makes really good sense

Answer (score 8):

In javascript (since 1.1), the `void` operator is used to evaluate an expression and return `undefined`.

See [ECMAScript Language Specification of the void operator](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.2)

So `void 0` is a correct and standard way to produce `undefined`.

As it is an operator, no parenthesis are needed.

Comment: Also the problem here is that one could override global undefined in JS and cause a lot of breakage. That way libraries using void 0 are more safe.