# Javascript: What is additional Zero in the if syntax?

Tags: javascript

I have been reading the javascript source of my company project and came across this

```
if (options.parse === void 0) options.parse = true;
```

Not sure what `0` does here?

Comment: `void <whatever> === undefined` [pure, native `undefined`].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452341/what-does-void-0-mean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`void` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.2) is very interesting: It accepts an operand, evaluates it, and then the result of the expression is `undefined`. So the `0` isn't extraneous, because the `void` operator requires an operand.

People use `void 0` sometimes to avoid the fact that the `undefined` symbol *can* be overridden (if you're not using strict mode). E.g.:

```
undefined = 42;
```

Separately, the `undefined` in one window is not `===` the `undefined` in another window.

So if you're writing a library and want to be a bit paranoid, either about people redefining `undefined` or that your code may be used in a multi-window situation (frames and such), you might not use the symbol `undefined` to check if something is `undefined`. The *usual* answer there is to use `typeof whatever === "undefined"`, but `=== void 0` works (well, it may not work in the multi-window situation, depending on what you're comparing it to) and is shorter. :-)

Comment: Wish I could give another +1 because of the use of 42 as an example number. Don't forget your towel.

Comment: Thanks a lot @T.J.Crowder, that explains it really well

Comment: One thing I like to do myself if I'm really paranoid about it is to throw all my JavaScript into a self-executing anonymous function and declare an extra formal parameter `undefined` (to which I don't pass anything). That will hide the global `undefined` and allow me to control the value and guarantee that it is actually undefined by simply not passing a value in for that parameter.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure I don't think that code will validate with `use strict`. ECMA5 defines `undefined` as a reserved word, therefore you can't use the name.

Comment: @AndreiNemes Yeah that's true, I found out the hard way

Comment: @AndreiNemes Shame, it would have been nice if they allowed that as a workaround or something. Thanks for pointing that out.