# Why use void(0)?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's assume for a moment that you must create a JavaScript link that doesn't have a meaningful `href`. (I know that this practice is questionable.) In this case, why do so many people use...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"> My link </a>
```

Knowing that `void(0)` evaluates to `undefined`, can I simply use the following logic?

```
<a href="javascript:undefined;"> My link </a>
```

Comment: You can redefine actually `undefined`, and void is useful for non trivial code in javscript links.

Comment: @Tim actually, you *could* in ES3. This has been changed in ES5 - you can no longer redefine `undefined` in the global scope, attempting to do so will fail silently.

Comment: I usually prefer `<a href="#">My link</a>`.  Just remember to add `event.preventDefault()` in the handler.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I thought that was only in strict mode.

Comment: @RocketHazmat if you will not prevent default behaviour in JS this method will add `#` to url + will scroll page to top

Comment: Even lesser, you also can use: `<a href="javascript:;"> My link </a>`

Comment: @hawkharris....  Curious, even if using the Strict DocType.  Why is it ever necessary to create an anchor that does not link.  Seems to me that you are creating clickable text that does not link to another site.  And would it not make more sense to create a <span /> instead

Comment: @JohnHartsock sometimes people use it to style a text like an anchor tag or just make it and leave to implement it later.

Comment: The first answer of this question deserved to be read : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: @Mohammad Areeb Siddiqui ... I understand your explanation, but I would say that using <a /> tags like that would be, in my opinion, a hack.  Utilizing proper semantics with HTML is important.  An anchor (<a /> tag) should be used for links, and not for styling, styling should be implemented using CSS.

Comment: It definitely is a hack, but it's a semantic grey area when considering single-page webapps, where clicking on a link gives the client a new page dynamically from the client, rather than asking for a new resource from the server.  Especially if it's stateful, where a populated `href` would be misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why people use `void(x)` instead of `undefined`?

Well both would work but `undefined` is a reserved variable and its value can be changed:

```
undefined = true;
```

This will give true instead of undefined.

Where as `void()` is a keyword *which always returns undefined.* Whatever you place inside the keyword:

`void('return false plox'); //will return false`

More info on this topic here: [What does `void 0` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452341/what-does-void-0-mean)

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZxxM/)

---

Note that `<a href="#">`  is not the same as it still acts as a link and will redirect you, where as the previous methods will cancel the event(similar to [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)).

**Update**

Since ECMAScript 5, the global `undefined` variable is no longer directly editable ([See for example Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8.5#Changed_functionality_in_JavaScript_1.8.5)). It now simply shadows the global variable as some have noted.

Comment: "`undefined` is a reserved variable and its value can be changed", really? Could you clarify? I've just made this quick test in my Chrome console : `undefined = true; undefined`, but `undefined` is still `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

There are three differences,

1. `void` evaluates the given expression and then returns the `undefined`
2. `window.undefined` is writable whereas `void` operator will always return `undefined`
3. `void` has fewer characters and results in smaller code, if you are using lot of them

Also, if you are using `void` to return `undefined` then you can simply use `void 0`, which is equivalent to `void(0)`.