# KineticJS getFillPatternX not working

Tags: kineticjs

I have a problem using getFillPatternX.
When I try:

```
console.log(polyTop.getFillPatternX);
```

The console output is:

```
function (){var a=this.attrs[b];return void 0===a?c:a}
```

I´ve expected a number and not this piece of code.
Is this a bug or am I not using it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return void 0===a?c:a` evaluates to

```
if(undefined === a) {
   return c;
}
else {
   return a;
}
```

See also:

- [What does `void 0` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452341/what-does-void-0-mean)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript

Or are you having problems calling the method? If that's what you wanted to do, then you forgot the brackets: `getFillPatternX()`

Comment: Thank you. I forgot the brackets <.<