# Shorter way to check for undefined in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Looking for a better idiom to use..

```
var x = module;  // Reference Error
var x = typeof module==='undefined' ? window : module;
```

is there a shorter way to check for the existence of module?

Comment: `module ? module : window`?

Comment: If you actually need to check that it's typeof undefined, no.

Comment: @thefourtheye that evaluates false even if module == false or module == 0 as well, so...

Comment: @remus I can purposefully set `module = undefined` as well ;)

Comment: You can use [void 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452341/what-does-void-0-mean)

    myVar === void 0;

Comment: Exactly! So it's all a giant gongshow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var x = module;  // Reference Error
```

Technically you're not checking for ***undefined*** - ie: if `module===undefined` (which many of the other answers are assuming) - you want to know whether the module is ***declared***.

In that case, your second example is the way to do it:

```
var x = typeof module==='undefined' ? window : module;
// replace window with whatever you want your fallback value to be
```

Answer (score -1):

I like to use double bang (!!) for that.

The first bang casts the variable to a Boolean, and the second undoes the logical that was performed by the first bang.

```
var x = !!module ? module : window;
```

This is also a shorter way to verify for null and undefined at the same time. This might be what you want.

Examples:

```
var foo = 1;
console.log(!!foo); //true

var bar = { name: "test" };
console.log(!!bar); //true

var module = null;
console.log(!!module); //false

var module = undefined;
console.log(!!module); //false
```

Comment: The problem with that, is that this checks for truthyness and not trueness. 
!!0 is still false.

Comment: The question states they want to check for a complex object existence "module", not for numbers. If you know no numbers or ZERO should be the variable value, double bang is perfect fine. In cases ZERO can be a value, you could check for zero as well. `!!module && module !== 0`