# How to do "if undefined" in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How would I get this in CoffeeScript?
This is the JS that I am trying to get :

```
if (value === undefined) {
  return model.get('isCompleted');
}
```

Basically, When I am trying this :

```
if value is undefined
  model.get 'isCompleted'
```

I am getting this in the JS :

```
if (value === void 0) {
  model.get('isCompleted');
}
```

Is there no way to display "undefined" without :

```
if value is `undefined`
```

I somehow don't want to use ``.

Comment: What's wrong with `value === void 0`? `void 0` returns `undefined`. It's often used because it is possible in older browsers to overwrite the value of `undefined` with something else.

Comment: Oh ok.. Sorry that was something that I was not aware of :/

Comment: See [What does `void 0` mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7452341/218196)

Answer (score 3):

In case you're not aware of the CoffeeScript [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators), that makes it real easy to check whether a variable is defined (i.e. it's not `undefined` or `null`). If it doesn't matter to you whether value is null or undefined, I'd use that. Use it like so:

```
if !value?
  model.get 'isCompleted'
```