# Is there any web technology available to hide a link in a html DOM at client side

Tags: javascript, html, web

I was participating in a special shopping event in a site (www.mi.com/in/) and I tried to view the HTML source through the browser in curious. I was looking for a code of button and I found the href is defined to `javascript: void(0)` and I thought they might have hidden the link somehow( maybe with some special web language) so nobody can direct go to the link. 
So I ask you, is there any present web technology available to hide a link in HTML code when parsing?
screenshot - take a look:[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452341/what-does-void-0-mean

Comment: Like @RobbyCornelissen has pointed out, it is indeed javascript.  And from a development point of view it's a best practice, rather than that of hiding links.  This is because it creates a separation of view & your business logic.

Comment: @Keith — Best practise would be to use a real link and prevent the default behaviour (as a fallback) or a button (because it isn't linking anywhere). `href="javascript:void(0)"` is terrible.

Comment: @Quentin  Your correct, if SEO is important.  But I was thinking from an App POV.  But saying that if SEO is important, I think the new micro data tagging etc is nicer.

Comment: @Keith — SEO is beside the point. It's better for humans. JavaScript fails for all sorts of reasons. Different UI components have different affordances.

Comment: @Quentin  Not sure what you mean, but if my javascript fails in App mode, I'd rather it fails end off.  Anyway, lets move on, were maybe a cross purposes here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes *Javascript void(0)* means this link will not perform functionality of href.
You can use HTML5  *data-* attributes and then use jquery to perform javascript operations on clicking of that link

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-action=clickElement]').click(function(){alert('the element is clicked')});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-action='clickElement'> 
  link
</a>
```