# What is the best way to do conditional rendering depending on the comparison of props and previous props?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to implement a green, or red glow on a row depending if a number increases or decreases.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Is there a way on `mapStateToProps` or during render to compare the two?

Comment: can you post your component code?

Comment: I would rather keep it generic.

Comment: Then I wouldn't expect a very useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the component's `render`-method only has access to the current props and state, you must keep information about how value changed in the current props and/or state. You must then indicate the change for (I assume) a brief amount of time.

## Where to set state so we know which color to show

There are several possibilities of where to do this listed below; **pick *one* of them, not all.** They all use the following utility fuction:

```js
function getChange(value, prevValue) {
    if (typeof prevValue === 'undefined') {
        // If previos value did not exist, don't count it as a change.
        // This is to avoid "feedback" the first time the value is rendered.
        return;
    }
    if (value === prevValue) {
        return;
    }

    return value < prevValue
        ? 'decrease'
        : 'increase';
}
```

#### 1. In [action creator](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions#action-creators)

Read current state before disptatching an action.
Note that this example requires you to use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk):

```js
const changeValueTo = (value) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const prevValue = getState().value;

    distpatch({
        type: 'SET_VALUE',
        change: getChange(value, prevValue),
        value: value
    });
}
```

#### 2. In [reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers)

```js
function valueReducer(state = { value: void 0, change: void 0 }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_VALUE':
            return {
                value: action.value,
                change: getChange(action.value, state.value)
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

PS: [`void 0` is just a safe way to get `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7452352/2054731).
PPS: We could just use `state = {}`, but I prefer to be specific.

#### 3. In component's [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

```js
class Value extends React.Component {

    state = {
        change: 'black'
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        return {
            value: nextProps.value,
            change: getChange(nextProps.value, prevState.value)
        };
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

#### 4. In other component lifecycle methods

Like e.g. in `componentDidUpdate` as suggested by [Bruno Mazzardo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50473108/2054731).

## Render color briefly

Here I change the color of the text, but you can of course change the background or anything else.

```css
/* css */
@keyframes red-fadeout {
    from {
        color: red;
    }
    to {
        color: black;
    }
}
@keyframes green-fadeout {
    from {
        color: green;
    }
    to {
        color: black;
    }
}
.decreased {
    animation: 3s red-fadeout;
}
.increased {
    animation: 3s green-fadeout;
}
```

```js
// React
class Value extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        const {
            value,
            change = '' // Assuming change is either 'increased', 'decreased' or falsy
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className={change}>{value}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to choose one of the approaches, not all of them. I will update my answer to make that clearer. For this exact case they are all OK, but in different situations it can be useful to know about the various options in case some fit the use case better than others.

Comment: Yeah, as he asked for a generic way, I think your answer is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState), make the check inside it, accessing this.props and this.state, that will be updated, and based on that, `setState({changed:this.props.number !== this.prevProps.number })`

React documentation about lifecycle  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate for reference

Comment: If i change state again the component will re-render and create an infinite loop.

I need to store: red, green somewhere.

Comment: no, because the component set true, one time, then prev prop and this.prop will be the same, and it will stop re rendering

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```js
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  if(props.step < 0)
  {
    return {counter: prevState.counter + props.step, color:'red'};
  }
  return {counter: prevState.counter + props.step, color:'blue'};
});
```

Based on this color in state component will render again.
For more info visit. [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)